# Why can't Vampires enter residences but other demons can in Buffy?

Tags: vampire, buffy-the-vampire-slayer

In *Buffy - The Vampire Slayer*, vampires are demon spirits inhabiting a human body:

> The canonical vampires, introduced in the first episode of the television series, are demonic spirits that inhabit human corpses.
>
> From the Wikipedia Article on [Vampires in the Buffyverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire_(Buffy_the_Vampire_Slayer))

In the Buffyverse, vampires cannot enter into a residence of a living being without being invited:

> Vampires cannot enter a human residence without having been invited once by a living resident
>
> Again from aforementioned Wikipedia Article.

As is seen in Episode 9 of Season 5, a demon can enter a house without being invitited. As it is stated in this question, in some mythologies, supernatural being cannot enter a house without being invited:

> Some of them include the idea that not only vampires but supernatural beings in general can not enter the house without an invitation.
>
> [From this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/45054/120088)

Has it ever been stated why a vampire cannot enter a residence without being invitited but a pureblood demon can, specially since a vampire is a demon spirit in a human body.

I am looking for an answer either from within the Buffyverse or a person being affiliated with the creation of it, e.g. Joss Whedon or a comic author explaining in an interview why it was decided to use that configuration.

Comment: Because vampires are vampires and demons are demons and that's just how the show was written. Presumably it's the same reason that holy water and crosses work too.

Comment: Vampires needing to be invited into someone's home is not a Buffy invention. That is a common trope for vampires dating back way before Buffy. There are quite a few questions on various StackExchange sites about this, including [Where did the idea of vampire invitation first originate?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/45052/), [Why do vampires have to be invited in?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65991/), [Why would vampires be incapable of entering a non-vampire human’s house uninvited?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/39842/), etc.

Comment: Vampires are the only supernatural monsters that I know of that are associated with having to be invited. I belive that dates back at least to Bram Stoker's Dracula, but may be an older tradition.

Comment: @RemyLebeau At first, I just thought it's weird that vampires, being demons in human body, have a restriction that demons do not. When I begun to check if somebody else had asked this question, I stumbled upon the question you posted and somebody posted that in some mythologies, all supernatural being must be invited. That made it even stranger.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen I thought so, too. Until I stumbled upon the answer I've quoted.